# I cant understand this code of php $_GET

Tags: php, forms

Please explain this code. What does `"status"` and the rest of the code mean?

```
<?php if (isset($_GET["status"]) AND $_GET["status"] == "thanks" 
        <?php // if status=thanks in the query string, display an thank you message instead of the form ?>
        <?php if (isset($_GET["status"]) AND $_GET["status"] == "thanks") { ?>
            <p>Thanks for the email! I&rsquo;ll be in touch shortly!</p>
        <?php } else {
```

Comment: It is already commented there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For example:
you add `?status=thanks` 
like

```
http://yourdomain.com/index.php?status=thanks
```

it will show the `<p>Thanks for the email! I&rsquo;ll be in touch shortly!</p>`

if there is `no status` or the `status is not thanks` it will not show that comment.

---

Example:

create file named test.php put it in htdocs localhost

```
<?php if (isset($_GET["status"]) AND $_GET["status"] == "thanks") : ?>
      <p>Thanks for the email! I&rsquo;ll be in touch shortly!</p>
<?php endif; ?>
```

try to go to your http://localhost/test.php and http://localhost/test.php?status=thanks and http://localhost/test.php?status=you

check what will be happened?

Comment: can you give me example plz

Answer (score 1):

Status is an variable from url which is checked for its value is set and value equals to "thanks".

Answer (score 1):

The below code embedded the html and php codes,
The use of below code is you can access both html tags and php values in same file.

```
<?php 

// if status=thanks in the query string, display an thank you message instead of the form 

?>
```

the above code, provide the php comment block, it give suggestion to developer.

```
<?php if (isset($_GET["status"]) AND $_GET["status"] == "thanks") { ?>
```

the above code used to get the value from url (using $_GET variable) (for example www.example.com/index.php?status=thanks)
if the status is set in url and the value is 'thanks' means, html tag will run otherwise run the else part.

```
<p>Thanks for the email! I&rsquo;ll be in touch shortly!</p>
```

else part,

```
<?php } else { 
// do somethink..!!
}
```

Answer (score 1):

if you r use $_GET method in php first a follow Your URL : https://www.example.in/webhp?status=thanks.check get variable status store value of thanks.After u check in php GET method. like the following code.

```
<?php 
   if($_GET['status'] == 'thanks'){?>
<p>Thanks for the email! I&rsquo;ll be in touch shortly!</p>
<?php }else{?>
 <p>Error</p>
<?php }?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need konw that:

@See-1 [PHP Predefined Variables](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.php)

---

@see-2 [$_GET is An associative array of variables passed to the current script via the URL parameters.](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php)

Comment: Also you can get your URL parameters by  [$_REQUEST](http://sg2.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.request.php)